# Two ways of defining tangent space

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Question states:

"Let $f:\Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R$ be a differentiable map and let $f:\Bbb R^{n+1} \to \Bbb R$ be given by $(x,z) \mapsto f(x) -z$ where $x \in \Bbb R^n$ and $z \in \Bbb R$. Let $M \subset \Bbb R^{n+1}$ be the graph of $f$ and $M' = F^{-1}(\{0\})$, i.e. the preimage of zero.

Part 1: Let $a \in \Bbb R^n$. Describe the tangent space on $M=M'$ at $(a,f(a)) \in \Bbb R^{n+1}$ using $f$ and using $F$.

Part 2: Show that these two descriptions agree."

I have proven that $M=M'$. Part 1 requires me to use the gradient of $f$ at some point and the fact that the normal vector is tangent to $M'$. For part 1, I tried expressing the tangent space $M$ as
$$
(a,f(a)) + \sum_{i=1}^n (e_i, \partial_if(a))r_i
$$
where $e_i \in \Bbb R^n$ is $i$th unit vector and $r_i \in \Bbb R$. Also, I expressed the tangent space $M'$ as 
$$
\{x \in \Bbb R^{n+1} : \nabla F(a) \cdot x = 0\}.
$$
But I couldn't really show they they are equal (for part 2). Am I doing something wrong here? I do feel like my first expression is overly complicated. Please don't include any linear algebra and express everything in terms of (advanced) calculus. I only know very few concepts in linear algebra.

Comment: Of course, M and M' are equal, but I just wanted to emphasize that the first equation is more related to f than F

Answer (score 1):

Note that for $a = (\hat a, a_{n+1}), x \in \def\R{\mathbf R}\R^{n+1}$ we have by definition of $F$
$$ F'(a)x = f'(\hat a)\hat x - x_{n+1} $$
that is 
$$ \nabla F(a)\cdot x = F'(a)x = 0 \iff x_{n+1} = f'(\hat a)\hat x $$
That is, any point $x$ on the tangent space at $a$ (second description) has the form 
\begin{align*}
   x &= (\hat x, x_{n+1})\\
     &= \bigl(\hat x, f'(a)\hat x\bigr)\\
     &= \sum_{i=1}^n x_i \bigl(e_i, f'(a)e_i\bigr)\\
     &= \sum_{i=1}^n x_i \bigl(e_i, \partial_i f(a)\bigr)
\end{align*}
which agrees with the first description (up to the shift $(a,f(a))$ which you didn't include in the second one).